# How to Auto login from my website to another website?

Tags: javascript, authentication

I come to you guys with a doubt about some code that I want to implement on my website.

Context:
Recently my employer asked me to include a live chat function on our website (which I used the gantry/rockettheme for wordpress to create), and after trying many wordpress plugins, and because he asked for it, I tried looking for something that would enable me to be online with a standalone app for windows, I mean, not be online in my browser.

In this endless search, I had the help of a coworker who told me about how we had an alibaba.com account and how it would be awesome if we could get our clients to chat with us through the alibaba trade manager software, it allows us to have a software, like skype or some other and reply to our customers through that.

Doubt:

Alibaba Trade manager requires the customer to be logged in to chat with the supplier, so I thought I might create an account and use it for every client so they could login and chat with us, the problem is, I don't want people to have to login with an account created by us with the data supplied by us, I wanted an automatic way of doing this, i mean, when people click the link, it would be coded with the username and password information so the customer would be logged in with our account, or else they would have just to press login and they would be chatting with us.

From what I gathered by looking at the source code of the login page of the chat,this is what they use for the username and password input:

Username:

```
<input type="text" id="xloginPassportId" acjs="passport" name="xloginPassport" 
maxlength="128" value="what was entered by the user" tabindex="1" style="width:200px" 
class="xman-input">
```

Password:

```
<input type="password" id="xloginPasswordId" acjs="password" name="xloginPassword"
maxlength="100" tabindex="2" style="width:200px" class="xman-input">
```

I don't know much about programming for the web, but from what I understand, I probably need to set the values for "xloginPassport" and "xloginPassword" when clicking so it would appear already there when following the link, right?

Is this feasible? how hard is it? would it involve security issues? Since alibaba might recognize this as a login bot?

Comment: if those trade software you are talking about doesn't provide an api i would say it's not possible and probably not as easy to do as you might think :)

Comment: hmm alright, as i said, i dont know much about this kind of programming, and i dont know if they provide any api, i will try to check this out, thanks for your reply anyway.

I saw something online about a software that lets you automate some processes, autoit, i know it allows you to login in a website like i want to, but i wanted to do it web based, i mean, a script where the link would be used to trigger it and it would login, kind of like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOeHnnPsJ4c @supernova

Comment: First, sending login credentials in a URL is always bad from a security standpoint. Second, this would only work if alibaba.com supports it, which they won't (see reason one). Third, this question is entirely too broad for this site. When you find the approach you wish to follow, feel free to ask when you encounter a specific problem with your actual code.